# добавление субтитров

Tags: javascript, html, видео

Не могу понять, как будет работать баттон с релизацией субтитров на видео.
Типа вкл и выкл субтитров на видео. Перепробовал методы, может я не так делаю.

**Код на JS**

```
let sub = document.querySelector('.buttonSub');
let video = document.querySelector('.video');
let textChange3 = document.querySelector('.changeText3');

sub.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.textTracks.mode) {
    video.textTracks.mode = 'showing';
    textChange3.textContent = 'SUBTITLE';
  } else {
    video.textTracks.mode = 'hidden';
    textChange3.textContent = 'NO SUBTITLE';
  }
  }, false);
```

**Код на HTML**

```
<video class="video" loop="" autoplay="" muted="" preload="auto">
      <source src="video/2Pac - Changes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <track kind="subtitles" label="English" srclang="en" src="video/2PacChanges1.vtt">
</video>

<div class="controls" data-state="hidden">
      <button class="btn buttonSub">
      <span class="changeText3">NO SUBTITLE</span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Не ожидал увидеть Тупака)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video#subtitle_implementation судя по этой инструкции, надо `for (var i = 0; i < video.textTracks.length; i++) {video.textTracks[i].mode = 'showing';}` перебирать в цикле `video.textTracks`

Comment: да Тупак)))
Да я изучал тот сайт с инструкциями, подумав это если у меня много субтитров на разных языках. 
Ладно. То есть в цикле сделать "on" и "off" ? А с условиями if else не катит?

Comment: `sub.addEventListener("click", function() {
   for (let i = 0; i < video.textTracks.length; i++) {
  if (video.textTracks[i].mode) {
    video.textTracks[i].mode = 'showing';
    textChange3.textContent = 'SUBTITLE';
  } else {
    video.textTracks[i].mode = 'hidden';
    textChange3.textContent = 'NO SUBTITLE';
  }}
  },false); `

Comment: Вроде получилось, кроме одного как обратно выключить не зашло(